# Docker directory structure in local system

Tags: directory, docker

I am using http://blog.thoward37.me/articles/where-are-docker-images-stored/ to understand the directory structure of the docker.That link suggests that every docker image entry under /var/lib/docker/graph/ has three fields json,layersize and /layer. But in my local system i dont find the /layer directory for any image.why is that so ?.Docker version iam using is 1.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No issues.I found the answer. The link i specified uses docker 0.8 and i am using docker 1.3.2. In the new docker version layers of rootfs are found in /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/